# Can I use multiple AND (&&) operators for the conditions in BASH

Tags: bash, boolean

```
if ssh server [ -d /path/to/dir1 && -d /path/to/dir2 && -d /path/to/dir3 && -d /path/to/dir1 ]
```

Please can anyone help me as i am new to bash.

Answer (score 1):

The `[ ]` is syntactic sugar for calling the POSIX `test` shell built-in. It does not allow `&&` within it.

The `[[ ]]` is the bash extension, which does allow `&&` to produce compound logical expressions.

So there is two ways to do what you want.

The POSIX way:

```sh
if [ -d /path/to/dir1 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir2 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir3 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir1 ]
then
    # Your code here
fi
```

Using the bash `[[ ]]` extension:

```sh
if [[ -d /path/to/dir1 && -d /path/to/dir2 && -d /path/to/dir3 && -d /path/to/dir1 ]]
then
    # Your code here
fi
```

In your case it looks like you are `ssh`ing to a server and then trying to see if all the conditions are true. In that case, in POSIX shell you can do

```sh
if ssh server sh -c '[ -d /path/to/dir1 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir2 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir3 ] && [ -d /path/to/dir1 ]'
then
    # Your code here
fi
```

<sup>(The `sh -c` is not strictly necessary if you know the user's login shell on the remote host is a POSIX shell.)</sup>

With the bash extension, you can do

```sh
if ssh server bash -c '[[ -d /path/to/dir1 && -d /path/to/dir2 && -d /path/to/dir3 && -d /path/to/dir1 ]]'
then
    # Your code here
fi
```

In both of the last two examples, the quoting is necessary.

Comment: The `sh -c` isn't necessary; `ssh server '[ -d /path/to/dir1 ] && ...'` would be sufficient.

Comment: Inside the [...] to do the test, it is possible to use -a to make a logic AND. See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica You link to the GNU man page for the `test` binary, which does support `-a` as a logical AND. However, I don't know if `-a` is supported as a logical AND for `test` shell built-ins for the entire `sh` family of shells. Even the GNU man page says "NOTE: Binary -a and -o are inherently ambiguous.  Use 'test EXPR1 && test EXPR2' or 'test EXPR1 || test EXPR2' instead."

Comment: @chepner Thanks, you're right. At first I thought `fish` didn't support `[ ]`, but it appears it does: https://fishshell.com/docs/3.0/commands.html#test says "For compatibility with other shells, the second form is available: a matching pair of square brackets ([ [EXPRESSION ] ])."

Comment: To be fair, I did assume some POSIX shell as the user's login shell. `sh -c` would be useful to ensure a POSIX shell even if the user's login shell is not POSIX-compliant.

Comment: From the page you posted, fish does support the -a: "COND1 -a COND2 returns true if both COND1 and COND2 are true.". But it is true that there here is no warranty about the support for -a in all the shells.